# Not sure how the admob works?

Tags: android, admob

Okay this may seem really stupid but i am really confused about it.

What do you search for in the admob search section when it asks you to search for an app?

Up until now i thought you search for whatever app you want (lets say clash of clans) and you will show clash of clans banner in your app. This way you will get money for advertising or actually referring people to their game. And the search for your own app option is for cases when you have to advertise your old app in your new app.

But i just saw a couple of tutorials and in those they said search for own app if you want to monetize your app and everyone does that in the tutorial. No one seems to search for other apps.

So can someone please clarify as to what i am supposed to do? What exactly should i search their? other apps or mine?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: what? @JonathonReinhart
Also, why are people down voting this? i asked what i was confused about and there's nowhere i can find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about how you chose what app will be ad on your app, i think its admob that does that. Because its different from each person, let,s say its most like to show a ad of games about shoot,fps to guys and for girls games more to girls,(just a idea i am not generalize), let me make other example I have been shearing for a app to make music, its probably that when i enter on your app the ad banner it will be about music production apps, this because cookies. This is how i think it works, but I am no sure